# Как создать тепловую карту на Python?

Tags: python

У меня есть датафрейм с истинными значениями и со средними предсказанными значениями.
Хочу сделать подобие тепловой карты (как на картинке), чтобы по x были истинные, а по y предсказанные и, чтобы они зависели от количества значений, но никак не могу понять как такое построить...

[image: heat map]

очень грубый пример датафрейма:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'True': [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 1], 
                   'Predicted': [1.1, 2.3, 4, 2.8, 4.1, 5, 1.2]})
```

Answer (score 0):

Тепловая карта, как в вашем примере на картинке, строится в случае, когда есть два набора колонок и на пересечении каждой колонки из одного набора с каждой колонкой из другого набора у нас есть какое-то число. На вашей картинке это один и тот же набор колонок, между которыми построена матрица корреляции и числа показывают степень корреляции каждой из колонок с каждой из других колонок. Так эта матрица и получается.

В вашем же примере данных даны всего две колонки значений. Можно, конечно, построить между ними матрицу корреляции 2x2, но там по диагонали всегда единицы и матрица симметрична относительно диагонали, так что фактически мы имеем всего одно число, странно было бы из него строить тепловую карту.

В общем, на данный момент совсем непонятно, что вы хотите. Скорее всего вам для начала нужно чётко сформулировать вашу задачу, а потом уже можно будет выбирать для неё оптимальное средство графического отображения. И в данном случае я сомневаюсь, что это будет тепловая карта.

Возможно, вам тут скорее нужен график распределения, построенный на разнице предсказанных и истинных значений. В случае "хороших" предсказаний он должен по форме напоминать нормальное распределение вокруг нулевой точки. Данных вы дали маловато, но что-то такое вырисовывается:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame({'True': [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 1], 
                   'Predicted': [1.1, 2.3, 4, 2.8, 4.1, 5, 1.2]})

sns.displot(df['Predicted'] - df['True'])
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно и график рассеяния попробовать построить:

```
sns.scatterplot(x=df['Predicted'], y=df['True'])
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И много чего ещё, но без конкретных данных угадать, какой график в итоге будет информативнее - это гадание на кофейной гуще.

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое за ответ! Я совсем новичок в этом поэтому мне тяжело даже сформулировать нормально. Вот мои данные: https://disk.yandex.ru/d/TX9p9uvcscFfzA. А хочу я сделать вот такую карту :https://disk.yandex.ru/i/u5xDAjDncTsEEg. То есть я хочу, чтобы именно визуально отображалось количество предсказаний, которые близки к правильным.